# Регистрация своего стиля в Project options -> Appearance

Tags: delphi, style, delphi-12-athens

Пытаюсь создать свой стиль. Открываю стандартный редактор стилей Bitmap Style Designer. Открываю существующий стиль и сохраняю его под новым именем. Была надежда, что он появится в Project options -> Appearance для дальнейшего использования в IDE. Но нет. Похоже нужна дополнительная регистрация.

Работаю под Windows 10 c Delphi 12.1